# enable use_modular_headers! in podfile in expo react-native project

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo, podfile

trying to use `@baronha/react-native-photo-editor` package in my expo project
it is a standalone expo app
i have done the integration on android
but i don't know how to enable use_modular_headers! in podfile for ios

as in documentation of [@baronha/react-native-photo-editor](https://github.com/baronha/react-native-photo-editor)  it is necessary to import `SDWebImage` and `SDWebImageWebPCoder` from Swift when building as static libraries. so need to set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies

implemented the package on android using Config Plugins
but cant find anything for ios

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue reported at https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/6332.
You may need modify your app.json, see e.g. https://rnfirebase.io/#expo

E.g.

```
"plugins": [
  "@react-native-firebase/app",
    ["expo-build-properties",
      {
        "ios": {
          "useFrameworks": "static"
        }
      }
    ]
],
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34591802)